# how can we solve this type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

```
for (int i = 2; i < k; i++)
{
    if ((tabl1[i].y != null) && (tabl[i].x != null))
    {
        double[] y2 = { 0, tabl1[i].y };
        double[] x2 = { tabl[i].x, 0 };
        PointPairList spl3 = new PointPairList(x2, y2);
    }
}
```

i want when `i=3` then create

```
double[] y3 = { 0, tabl1[i].y }; 
double[] x3 = { tabl[i].x, 0 }; 
PointPairList spl3 = new PointPairList(x3, y3);
```

when `i=4` then create

```
double[] y4 = { 0, tabl1[i].y };
double[] x4 = { tabl[i].x, 0 }; 
PointPairList spl4 = new PointPairList(x4, y4);
```

when `i=5` then create

```
double[] y5 = { 0, tabl1[i].y };
double[] x5 = { tabl[i].x, 0 };
PointPairList spl5 = new PointPairList(x5, y5);
```

etc..

Comment: ..is a for loop really required for that? You're using the loop when you already know the indexes you want..

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:facebook-c#-sdk]? Is that really relevant?

Comment: What you want then to do with those spl1, spl2, spl3, spl4, etc. ?

Comment: i knw the indexes but i dont know how many i should create ... " k " is a int giving by the using of the application ... and i need to change their name ... like i give the exemple above thx !

Comment: can i write double [] y[i] ={ 0, tabl1[i].y };
double[] x[i]= { tabl[i].x, 0 };
PointPairList spl[i] = new PointPairList(x[i], y[i]);
hope u understand what i meant

Comment: How are table1 and tabl defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is absolutely not clair... like this?

```
private static Dictionary<String, PointPairList> s_PointPairLists = new Dictionary<String, PointPairList>();

private static void BuildPointPairLists(Int32 limit)
{
    for (Int32 i = 2; i < limit; ++i)
    {
        if ((tabl[i].x != null) && (tabl[i].y != null))
        {
            Double[] x = { 0, tabl[i].y };
            Double[] y = { tabl[i].x, 0 };

            s_PointPairLists[("ppl" + i.ToString())] = new PointPairList(x, y);
        }
    }
}

public static PointPairList(Int32 index)
{
    String reference = "ppl" + index.ToString();

    if (s_PointPairs.Contains(reference))
        return s_PointPairs[reference];

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a function and call that:

```
public PointPairList GetPointPairList(int index) {
    if (tabl[index].y != null && tabl[index].x != null) {
        double[] x = { 0, tabl[index].y };
        double[] y = { tabl[index].x, 0 };
        return new PointPairList(x, y);
    }
    return null;
}

// ...
for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
    PointPairList ppl = GetPointPairList(i);
    // ...
}
```

Does that not do what you require? Without more context it's hard to tell..

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, PointPairList>();
for (int i = 2; i < k; i++)
{
    if ((tabl1[i].y != null) && (tabl[i].x != null))
    {
        double[] y2 = { 0, tabl1[i].y };
        double[] x2 = { tabl[i].x, 0 };
        dict.Add(i, new PointPairList(x2, y2));
    }
}
```

With that you can easily get e.g. forth item in this way: `dict[4]`.